# Get Android Styled Attributes from AttributeSet

Tags: android, android-layout

In a custom view I can get the custom attrs value from the AttributeSet (shown below). But how do I get the Android attributes? For instance, how do I access android:background or android:text ? android.R.styleable isn't allowed.

```
<mine.custom.RangeSeekBar
    custom:selectedMinValue="2"
    custom:selectedMaxValue="4"
    android:background="@drawable/my_skin" />


public RangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RangeSeekBar, defStyle, 0);
    selectedMinValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_selectedMinValue, selectedMinValue);
    selectedMaxValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_selectedMaxValue, selectedMaxValue);
    minRangeValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_minRangeValue, minRangeValue);
    maxRangeValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_maxRangeValue, maxRangeValue);
    a.recycle();
}
```

Edit: Is this the standard way?

```
final String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    int xmlRes = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "background", -1);
    String xmlText = attrs.getAttributeValue(xmlns, "text");
```

Comment: Not really sure, but what if you use "android.R.attr.text" or "android.R.attr.background" instead of "int xmlRes = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "background", -1)"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess we'll go with this:

```
final String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
int xmlRes = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "background", -1);
String xmlText = attrs.getAttributeValue(xmlns, "text");
```

Comment: With text this will return the id not the text if you dont use hard coded text but string refs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204017/get-android-styled-attributes-from-attributeset#comment27179039_13540014), it's not the canonical way to do that. Besides, this actually works only for hard coded strings.
A sample from [android source code for Preference class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/preference/Preference.java#Preference) may help:

```
  TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                 com.android.internal.R.styleable.Preference, defStyle, 0);
         for (int i = a.getIndexCount(); i >= 0; i--) {
             int attr = a.getIndex(i); 
             switch (attr) {
                 ...
                 case com.android.internal.R.styleable.Preference_key:
                     mKey = a.getString(attr);
                     break;
                 ...
             }
```

Comment: Sadly the "com.android.internal.R.styleable.*" resources are hidden, so can't be used outside of the Android source code. I used something similar to the answer give by user123321.